# Linking error CXX

Tags: c++, ubuntu

I have installed few packages. I've installed, build and when I make the "make" command, I get a linking error... Here the error :

```
LINKING CXX executable psmoveinput
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lboost_thread-mt
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lboost_program_options-mt
```

I have an Makefiles in the program that I want install, in these folder, I have "link.txt" and there is -lboost_thread-mt, -lboost_program_options-mt.

I've installed lboost-dev... I forget the number of package that I have installed but the linking is not good, I don't know how can I solve it. I'm an amateur in ubuntu. Please help me.

> OS : Kali GNOME 3.4.2

Answer (score 0):

You should add the library path of your boost installation to the linker path by passing the `-L` argument on compiation.

e.g. `gcc foo.cpp -o foo -L path/to/boost/library -lboost_thread-mt -lboost_program_options-mt`